# How do I run my automation scripts which include UI interaction on an Octopus tentacle using the Octopus Server?

Tags: nunit, specflow, octopus

I have a batch file which uses nunitconsole runner to run my tests.
It's a combination of nunit framework and specflow.
When I run the batch file on the Octopus tentacle it works as expected.

However, if I create a step in the Octopus server to trigger this batch file, none of the UI related things happen.
Any setting or prerequisite is required for this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com.
Please take some time to read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and
["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Are you using a UI automation framework like Selenium to run the tests?

Comment: I'm using Ranorex and a combination of Nunit & specflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago I had a similar situation, this is because Octopus server runs as a service, due to this, you can not have anything that requires a window or interaction to run, however a workaround could be, execute a scheduled task through Octopus to execute your batch, so you will execute in a non background way.

Comment: "...execute a scheduled task through Octopus to execute your batch, so you will execute in a non background way." -- >
1) Could you please elucidate a bit more? 
2) And when you say Octopus, are u referring to server or tentacle?
3) In any case how do I schedule a task?

Thanks a bunch in advance! :)

Comment: 1) A scheduled task is like a script that will be executed automatically in a specific time, if you use this scheduled task to run your batch, you will be able to see the normal behavior for your batch, it means UI interaction. So maybe create a powershell script in Octopus that executes a scheduled task already created in the tentacle, or also include the creation of scheduled task in the powershell script

Comment: 2) 3) In this case, the powershell script could be implemented in one step of your process(Octopus project), the scheduled task could be exists or not, in case that you want create the scheduled task will be easy (see this link [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/for-windows-7-and-less-1042e194)), so you will have a scheduled task that executes your batch and octopus just will activate this scheduled task(octopus project-server->scheduled task will live in tentacle->your batch will live in tentacle)

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks a lot! Appreciated!! Thanks a bunch again..!!

Comment: Great!, please don't forget mark this answer like useful. Thanks in advance!